# How can I generate programmatically a MIDI event on iPad

Tags: ipad, midi, coremidi

I would like to test a MIDI app and want to generate some MIDI events without attaching a physical keyboard. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using CoreMidi, setup your app to use MIDINetworkSessions.  Once you advertise your iPad over the network, use any MIDI sequencer etc to connect to it and send messages over WiFi.

That way you can test without constantly unplugging/replugging things, and while still tethered to Xcode which is a huge bonus.

The other option would be to create an artificial MIDIPacketList and send it directly to your handler, but this is a lot less flexible.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean sending a MIDI event *to* an iPad, then you could use a simple program like [Rondo](http://www.fracturedsoftware.com/rondo/) to play a MIDI file to it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need some source codes to generate MIDI events on iPad.

I found this one. It is a wrapper class of CoreMIDI, and it has source codes of sending/receiving some MIDI events.

RCTMidiLib
https://github.com/recotana/RCTMidiLib

I connect iPad and Mac wirelessly, and successfully send/receive MIDI events using the test application on iPad.